# Code to Select Multiple Columns in an Excel Table

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA. I need a modification in my code so that I would be able to proceed further.

I want to select multiple table columns in an excel table.
Here is my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)

Range("tbl[[Column1]:[Column5]]").Select
```

When I put the table name, it works. but I want to use variable which I have used in my code to select the table columns.

Comment: Try: `Range(tbl & "[[Column1]:[Column5]]")`

Comment: thanx scott. it really helped me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use concatenation to use a variable as a table name.

Here is the code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)

Range(tbl & "[[Column1]:[Column5]]").Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

There are many ways to do this:

you could use:

```
Range("A:E").Select ' example selects columns from A to E
```

Otherwise you could also make it by using an array example:

```
Sub test()

 Dim x, y As Range, z As Integer
    x = Array(1, 5)
    Set y = Columns(x(0))
    For z = 1 To UBound(x)
        Set y = Union(y, Columns(x(z)))
    Next z
    y.Select
  End Sub
```

but this depends of what you needs

Best regards

Daniel