# VBA for selecting a number of columns in an excel table

Tags: excel, excel-tables, vba

As I learned [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) (also [quoted in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541445/select-entire-column-in-table-using-excel-vba)) the following code can be used to select the data-body of column 3 in `Table1`:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Select
```

I need help to **select a number of columns together** - say columns 3 to 5, or columns X to X+3 .

Using answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041167/code-to-select-multiple-columns-in-an-excel-table) question I manged to go halfway by using actual column names:

```
Range("Table1[[Column3]:[Column5]]").Select
```

But I need to be able to use column numbers instead of names, as they will be the result of a function (i.e. columns X to X+d).

Comment: `Range(Cells([rowNum],[colNum]),Cells([rowNum],[colNum])`?

Comment: Try that: `Range("Table1[[Column" & CStr(X) &"]:[Column" & CStr(X+d) & "]]").Select`.

Comment: @BruceWayne this would work but i'd have to mess around with row numbers, and so wouldn't be using the table features (eg. ability to select a table column)

Comment: @RafaelMatos your suggestion would work if those were the actual column names. This may be likely in other cases as these are default names, in my case they were just an example, the actual names are different

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For a contiguous range, simply resize a single column.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 3).Select
```

For a more complex selection, use Union to collect them prior to the .Select process.

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Union(.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange, _
          .ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange, _
          .ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange).Select
End With
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020#28700020) for better methods.

Comment: Resize... Nailed it!!

Comment: I tried this code to copy specific columns from a table (3,4 and 6) but when I paste the result I get the columns 3,4,5 and 6. Why does that work for Select but not for Copy?

Comment: I just realized that it actually works when I paste it into an Excel sheet. When I paste it into an HTML email (Outlook), it also pastes all columns between the selection. I really don't understand why this is happening...

Comment: I also get the same behavior when pasting it into Word. (it copies the entire selection)

Answer (score 3):

Use Columns method on DataBodyRange which can take a relative table range such as `"A:B"`

So if you wanted the first two columns you could write: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Columns("A:B").Select`

But what if you wanted to select based on a relative column number?
Create a few functions to convert numbers to this string:

```
Sub selectMultipe()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Columns(getRangeStr(1, 2)).Select
End Sub

'Get Range String
Function getRangeStr(startColNum As Long, endColNum As Long) As String
    startCol = ColLtr(startColNum)
    endCol = ColLtr(endColNum)

    getRangeStr = startCol + ":" + endCol
End Function

'Convert column number to letter
Function ColLtr(iCol As Long) As String
    If iCol > 0 And iCol <= Columns.Count Then ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, iCol).Address(0, 0), 1, "")
End Function
```

Note: The column number to letter function was found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/623443-vba-code-convert-number-into-column-letter.html)

Comment: Typically, the 'column letter' is retrieved by splitting the absolute address on the *$* symbol and taking the second element of the array but that works too.

Comment: This is a little complex for my present needs, but might be useful in other situations - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way that I have used is this

```
ActiveSheet.Range("tblResult[" & .ListColumns(3).name & "]:tblResult[" & .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).name & "]").Select
```

which in this case selects column 3 and the remaining columns.

Comment: Nice answer. Welcoce to Stack-Overflow!